# Compute Gradients in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently, I am trying to do some experiment in the field of learning to learn. However, I found that there are two functions in Tensorflow which can help me compute the gradients. Sometimes they can give me the same answer, but sometimes not. I do not know the reason for that case.

The following is my function which has an explicit equation.

```
def function_1(x):
    return tf.sin(x) * x + tf.cos(x) * tf.exp(x)
```

Then, I use the following two functions to compute the gradients and obtain the same result.

```
x = tf.Variables(2.0, name='x')
gradient_1 = tf.gradients(function_1(x), [x])
gradient_2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().compute_gradients(function_1(x), var_list=[x])
```

However, when I try to use both of them to compute the gradients of functions which do not have explicit equations, they provide my different answer. For example, I sample functions from Gaussian Process and the details as the following.

```
def expectation(x):
    point = np.reshape(np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 300), (300, 1))
    kernel_matrix_np = np.exp(-(point - np.transpose(point))**2 / (2 * 1.5**2))

    def reference_point():
        covariance = kernel_matrix_np
        np.random.seed(100)
        sampled_funcs = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.ones(len(point)), covariance)
        return sampled_funcs
    ref_point = tf.transpose(tf.convert_to_tensor(reference_point(), dtype=tf.float32))
    point = tf.reshape(tf.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 300), (300, 1))
    kernel_matrix_tf = tf.exp(-(point - tf.transpose(point))**2 / (2 * 1.5**2))
    inverse_kernel_matrix = tf.matrix_inverse(kernel_matrix_tf)
    kernel_vector = tf.exp(-(x - tf.transpose(point))**2 / (2 * 1.5**2))
    mu = tf.matmul(kernel_vector, inverse_kernel_matrix)
    ref_point = tf.expand_dims(ref_point, axis=1)
    mu = tf.matmul(mu, ref_point)
    return mu

x = tf.Variable(2.0, name='x')
gradients_1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().compute_gradients(expectation(x), var_list=[x])
graidents_2 = tf.gradients(expectation(x), [x])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('The gradient one is', sess.run(gradients_1))
    print('The gradient two is', sess.run(graidents_2))
```

The results are as the following.

```
The gradient one is [(-24.727448, 2.0)]
The gradient two is [-27.727448]
```

I am not sure how where the problem is and how both functions work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradients are calculated exactly the same way. You are having **precision issues**, probably because of your exponentiations + matrix inversions.

Here a version with `float64` instead of `float32` for which gradients are indeed the same:

```
def expectation(x):
    point = np.reshape(np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 300), (300, 1))
    kernel_matrix_np = np.exp(-(point - np.transpose(point))**2 / (2 * 1.5**2))

    def reference_point():
        covariance = kernel_matrix_np
        np.random.seed(100)
        sampled_funcs = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.ones(len(point)), covariance)
        return sampled_funcs
    ref_point = tf.transpose(tf.convert_to_tensor(reference_point(), dtype=tf.float64))  # <---
    five64 = tf.convert_to_tensor(5.0, dtype=tf.float64)  # <---
    point = tf.reshape(tf.linspace(-five64, 5.0, 300), (300, 1))  # <---
    kernel_matrix_tf = tf.exp(-(point - tf.transpose(point))**2 / (2 * 1.5**2))
    inverse_kernel_matrix = tf.matrix_inverse(kernel_matrix_tf)
    kernel_vector = tf.exp(-(x - tf.transpose(point))**2 / (2 * 1.5**2))
    mu = tf.matmul(kernel_vector, inverse_kernel_matrix)
    ref_point = tf.expand_dims(ref_point, axis=1)
    mu = tf.matmul(mu, ref_point)
    return mu

x = tf.Variable(2.0, dtype=tf.float64, name='x')  # <---
gradients_1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().compute_gradients(expectation(x), var_list=[x])
graidents_2 = tf.gradients(expectation(x), [x])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('The gradient one is', sess.run(gradients_1))
    print('The gradient two is', sess.run(graidents_2))
```

(the lines i've altered are marked with a fancy arrow comment)

My output:

```
>>> The gradient one is [(-21.5, 2.0)]
>>> The gradient two is [-21.5]
```

Note that `compute_gradients` from optimiser also returns the value of `x` itself. That's why you have a tuple instead of only the gradient (first value).

Comment: Thank you for your patient explanation.